# chdir doesn't work

Tags: working-directory

I'm in the browsing directory mode how can I change the current directory to that one I'm browsing? At least manually. But ":chdir ." doesn't work

Moreover, in the config file I have "set autochdir" and it still doesn't change it always automatically

Comment: the command is called `:cd`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, doesn't work

Comment: Please be specific. What did you do, what did you expect, did you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

The `acd` option should do what you want, you should describe, why and how it **doesn't work**.

I don't want the path change to happen automatically, so in my vimrc file, I have this:

```
"Switch to current dir
nnoremap <Leader>cd :cd %:p:h<cr>
```

Comment: how do you create a new file in the directory you're browsing?

Answer (score 1):

Just type `c`. From `:help netrw-c` (or just execute `:help netrw` and search for `directory`):

> By default, ... the current directory will not track the browsing directory.  ...  [I]n order to make the two directories the same, use the "c" map (just type c).  That map will set Vim's notion of the current directory to netrw's current browsing directory.

For an acknowledgement of the `'autochdir'` (`'acd'`) problem, see:

```
netrw-incompatible
```